# can i use iphone's APIs in my web applications?

Tags: iphone

i want to create an iphone web app using windows

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to know if you can access hardware capabilities of the iPhone in your web application?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean writing an iPhone app using HTML and JavaScript, look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/).  This lets you create an actual iPhone app that can access the camera, GPS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

http://cappuccino.org/